# Click stream and similarity matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sequence, similarity, clickstream

I have a list of sequences that represent a user navigation path thru a website.
The have the form of:

S1 = [2,5,3,7,3]

S2= [2,7,3,9,4,3,5,6,1]

And so on…

As you can see the length of the sequences does not have to be the same.
I am trying to compute a similarity matrix to give as input to a clustering algorithm, in this case DBSCAN.
The problem that I am having is that every example I find on internet, the sequences used have the same lengths.
So the main challenge I am trying to address would be to compute a similarity matrix using sequences of different lengths.
I would appreciate some help!

Comment: You might want to consider using the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: See if Dynamic Time Warping helps. It allows for different length sequences. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping